# Typo3 6 and Extbase: how to use composer files, autoload.php

Tags: php, typo3

What I want to do is use the elasticsearch php client in a typo3 extbase controller. Now I created a composer.json and did the composer install, now I have a vendor directory next to my typo3 directories.

But what do I do next? Can I somehow tell typo3 to use the autoload.php or is there another way to load the classes? I'm kinda helpless.

Answer (score 0):

If you want composer support, then you should consider upgrading to `TYPO3 7.6 LTS`.
You can find some basic documentation about [composer at the official website](https://composer.typo3.org/).

Comment: that is, unfortunately, out of the question